# change the name of my computer

Tags: windows-7, rename

When I received my laptop as a gift from my boyfriend I was showing my appreciation by naming it Heman's Woman, however, now that comes up when I upload files. I have the workaround for it so that doesn't appear but I'd like to not have to do that and just upload without that appearing next to any of my files. I've followed a number of different ways to fix this.

Under `System Properties>Computer Name/Domain Changes`
my computer is listed as StephsComputer and it states:

```
Full computer name:
StephsComputer
```

Under User Profiles it uses both names: `STEPHSCOMPUTER\HemansWoman`.

Mostly I see it when I upload at sites, say for instance a resume. I'd really prefer not to be Hemans Woman when applying for jobs, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Is Heman's Woman your computer's name or your user name? It looks like it is the user name.

Comment: The name of your computer would not be displayed when you upload files.

Comment: "now that comes up when I upload files" - Where are you uploading files that publicly displays the local path you uploaded them from?

Answer (score 1):

STEPHSCOMPUTER is your computer's name and Hemanswoman is your username. 
Go to Start -> Run -> type **control userpasswords2** then press Enter. Choose Hemanswoman and click on **Properties**. Change your username to something more fitting. Then logout and login again, this time with your new username.

Comment: The path I found was: Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\User Accounts Then 'Change account name'

Answer (score 1):

manu has given a good answer, but you may want to consider simply adding a new user account to your machine and log in to that for your serious stuff (job apps etc), and maintain the HemansWoman account for other laptop use (chatting with the bf, for instance :-)  Just a thought.